# Bootstrap4: NavBar move from the left

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I want to display my links to the right of the page

I have tried mr-auto but it does not work

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- for **right align** on **desktop only**:
  adding the class `justify-content-end` to your `div class="collapse navbar-collapse... >` will make the links right aligned: you can check the code snippet below also:
- for **right align** on **mobile collapsible menu also**:
  add css: `.nav-link{text-align: right;}`

**complete snippet:**

```css
.nav-link{text-align: right;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav ">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```